# Fit an image into the fixed height and width View container(React native)

Tags: css, react-native

As you can see on the image below I am having trouble fitting the above image to the green layout and the bottom image to the blue layout

Here's my code

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View
    style={{
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 3,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    }}>
    <Image
      source={require('../../Assets/Images/LoginUI/sample_1.jpg')}
      style={styles.imageBelow}
    />
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }}>
    <Image
      source={require('../../Assets/Images/LoginUI/sample_2.png')}
      style={styles.imageBelow}
    />
  </View>
</View>;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fdeb1d',
  },
  imageBelow: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

What I am trying to do is the BOTTOM IMAGE will cover all the blue container then the UPPER IMAGE will cover the whole green image but I need to exactly fit them on the container. A bit help, please

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example image of the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You could use `resizeMode= 'cover'`. But this will crop the image while maintaining the image's aspect ratio.

### Option 2

You could create a custom `Image` component that has Dynamic height according to image `aspectRatio` and `View width`.

```
class DynamicImage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    aspectRatio: 1,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // this.ImageDimension_uri()
    // this.ImageDimension_local()
  };

  // If source is uri
  ImageDimension_uri = () => {
    Image.getSize(
      this.props.source,
      (width, height) => {
        this.setState({ aspectRatio: width / height });
      },
      (err) => {
        // console.log({ err })
      }
    );
  };
  // If source is require()
  ImageDimension_local = () => {
    const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.props.source);
    this.setState({ aspectRatio: width / height });
  };

  render() {
    const { aspectRatio } = this.state;
    const { width } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{ aspectRatio, width }}>
        <Image
          {...this.props}
          style={{ flex: 1, width: undefined, height: undefined }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and use it

```
// const source = { uri: '' }
// const source = require('')

<DynamicImage {...{ source }} width={100} />
```

Comment: ```Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.``` i am currently having a problem using this code sir . Sorry

Comment: Please refer [https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/dynamic-image](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/dynamic-image)